# Object Oriented Programming for datalist in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a basic search filter that works as intended, highlighting the selected option from a datalist. However, the code is not exactly optimized.

You can find my JS Fiddle below.

https://jsfiddle.net/ao0s3k6L/2/

Right now the code has lots of redundancies if I want to add new objects. Specifically with operations such as the ones below.

`{$(".fishtype:not(#salmon_fish)").hide();
 if ($("#salmon_fish").css('display') == 'none')
 {$("#salmon_fish").show();}}`

Adding new objects would have me repeating the three lines above every time. How would I go about making my code more object oriented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can optimize your code like below,

```
$(document).on("input", "#fish", function() {
   $(".fishtype").hide().filter(":contains("+ this.value +")").show();
});
```

There is no need to construct `if-else` ladder.

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ao0s3k6L/3/)

Comment: @JasonChen Glad to help! :)